# Loading image during ajax process not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code looks like this...

`div` to show content and loading image:

```
<div id="adS" style="float: left; width: 70%">
    <div id="loading-image" style="background-image: url('images/processing.gif'); display: none;">


    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
        $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
          var gen = $("input[name='radGen']:checked").val();
          var mt = $('#selMtQ').val();
          var agf = $('#agf').val();
          var agt = $('#agt').val();
          var rel = $('#religQ').val();
          var cast = $('#selCstQ').val();
          $('#loading-image').show();
           $.post('adSearch.php',{gen:gen,mt:mt,agf:agf,agt:agt,rel:rel,cast:cast}, function(data){
             $("#adS").html(data);
             $('#loading-image').hide();
           });
           return false;
        });
      });
```

The loading image is only shown once on click event and not every time I click the search li... :(

Need help...

Comment: Maybe the server respond quickly and so you think image wasn't shown. Set an `alert()` before `$('#loading-image').hide();` to test it or use some kind of animation, e.g: `$('#loading-image').hide(1000);`

Comment: I bet you're replacing you div "adS" with html code which does not have a div called "loading-image"

Answer (score 0):

To check if it is the server that is responding very quickly you could test it with the setTimeOut() function at the ajax process. If the picture is not shown then it is not the server that is very quickly but something else. But more of your code is needed then to understand what is going on.